# How to clone DMG image to another partition, or USB partition?

Tags: dmg-image

Hackintosh probably is not welcome in here, but question is about cloning DMG image to any partition on HDD or USB drive...

I know that there's TRANSMAC software, but this one wants to format full USB drive, and I have 200gb of my files you know.. so it's impossible. All I want is to put DMG content to partition of my HDD (which is already created) or to USB drive partition.. I can't find software for this task, it's netbook, so no DVDroms in here.. How do people clone ISO image to the second partition of linux distro and installing from them??